# How to extract last digit from string which contains chars and numbers

Tags: javascript

How can i extract from string only last number which should be "5"?

```
var str = "1000040928423195 points added to your balance";
var str = parseInt(str);
var lastNum = str.substr(str.length - 1);
console.log(lastNum);
```

Comment: this is a very specific solution i.e for exactly what you have in your example:

var str = "1000040928423195 points added to your balance";
var str = parseInt(str);
var lastNum = str.toString().substr(str.length - 1);
console.log(lastNum[lastNum.length-1]);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given your string...

```
var str = "1000040928423195 points added to your balance";
```

... we can extract all the numbers with a regex...

```
var onlyNumbers = str.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

... and, finally, get the last one:

```
var lastNumber = onlyNumbers.substring(onlyNumbers.length - 1);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var str = "1000040928423195 points added to your balance";
var onlyNumbers = str.replace(/\D/g,'');
var lastNumber = onlyNumbers.substring(onlyNumbers.length - 1);

console.log(lastNumber);
```

Comment: You can also do `numbers = str.split(' ')[0];`

Comment: Indeed. But this snippet works for any string, like this: `var str = "654ttgdhd7ttrhd"`, returns `7`.

Answer (score 4):

Just add [toString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp) after parseInt

```js
var str = "1000040928423195 points added to your balance";
var str = parseInt(str).toString();
var lastNum = str.substr(str.length - 1);
console.log(lastNum);
```

Comment: I'd avoid using `parseInt()` without the base argument, this can be problematic old browsers. So it would be `parseInt(str, 10)` to be consistent.

Comment: yes I know but its 2016, old browsers what ? and Im just completing OP  question :)

Comment: :o I was answering another question which was about old browsers! Sorry to intrude :) anyway it's quite a nice bit of factual fun ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex like `/\d+(\d)/`

```
var str = "1000040928423195 points added to your balance";
str.match(/\d+(\d)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

After your second line, `str` isn't a string any more; it is an integer.  As such, you can extract the last digit with `str % 10`; if necessary, convert that to a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try parsing it with a Regular Expression like so :)

```js
string = "120394023954932503 fdsaf fdsaf dasfasd";
regex = /([0-9]*)/g;
match = regex.exec(string);
last_num = match[0].substr(match[0].length - 1);
console.log(last_num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="string_val"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex `\d+(\d)` to match multiple digits followed by a digit.

`\d` will occupy as many as possible, where `(\d)` will match the last.

Then get the last number from the first group `[1]`.

```js
var str = "1000040928423195 points added to your balance";

var match = /\d+(\d)/g.exec(str)[1];

console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var digit = /.*(\d)/.exec("awoo123awoo")[1];
```

> 3